# Finding All Solutions For $\sin(x) = x^2$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Hello everyone how can I find the count of the solution for $\sin(x) = x^2$?

I know there is a one solution in $x = 0$ and for the other solutions I tried to find the extreme point of the function: $y = x^2 - \sin(x)$ and $y'$ is:

$y' = 2x -\cos(x)$ but I don't know how to solve this equation.

Comment: Why are you interested in the extrema of the function, at this stage? You're supposed to find the roots of the function, which usually have little to do with the extrema. But yes, you are correct that $x=0$ is one of the solutions. You can find the other one with numerical methods. It's between $x=0.8$ and $x=0.9$.

Comment: Try graphing $x^2$ and $\sin(x)$ separately on same paper by hand and you will see the solutions

Comment: First thing if I will find the extreme point I will know how to draw the graph of the function and I will see that there are 2 solutions. Second thing how do you know that the second solution is between $x = 0.8$ and $x = 0.8$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite obvious that there are no solutions when $x<0$, so we will look for $x\ge0$. You have found that $x=0$ satisfies the equation. Let's analyze for $x>0$:

Take $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=\sin(x)$.

For $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$, some calculations give $f(\frac{\pi}{4})\approx 0.625$ while $g(x) \approx 0.7$: $$f(\frac{\pi}{4}) < g(\frac{\pi}{4})$$

For $x=1$, $f(1)=1$ but $g(1)<1$ since $\sin(x)$ is increasing for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ and $\sin(\pi/2)=1$, then $$f(1)>g(1)$$
which means $f(x)$ exceeds $g(x)$ between $(\pi/4,1)$ and intersect in this inteval. Now you just need to prove that they can't intersect more than once.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You are welcome. You may ask for a further hint to prove the uniqueness of the solution if you can't take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for the fun of it !*

There is no explicit solution for the zero of function $$f(x)=2x -\cos(x)=0$$ If you need it, use Newton method which will converge quite fast as shown in the table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.000000 \\
 1 & 0.500000 \\
 2 & 0.450627 \\
 3 & 0.450184
\end{array}
\right)$$ Another solution could be a series expansion
$$2x -\cos(x)=1-2 x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^6}{720}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ and use series reversion to get
$$x=t-\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{t^3}{8}-\frac{11 t^4}{192}+\frac{3 t^5}{128}-\frac{121
   t^6}{23040}-\frac{19 t^7}{5120}+O\left(t^8\right)\quad \text{where}\quad t=\frac{1-f(x)}2$$ Making $f(x)=0$ that is to say $t=\frac 12$, you should get, as an *approximation*,
$$x =\frac{531037}{1179648}\approx 0.450166$$

Amazing would be to use the $\color{red}{1,400}$ years old approximation
$$\cos(x) \simeq\frac{\pi ^2-4x^2}{\pi ^2+x^2}\qquad (-\frac \pi 2 \leq x\leq\frac \pi 2)$$  which would lead to the cubic equation
$$2 x^3+4 x^2+2 \pi ^2 x-\pi ^2=0$$
$$x=-\frac{2}{3} \left(1-\sqrt{3 \pi ^2-4} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{63 \pi ^2-32}{4 \left(3 \pi
   ^2-4\right)^{3/2}}\right)\right)\right)\approx 0.449785$$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \text {We know that } -1 \le sin(x) \le 1$$
$$ \text {So, x has to be within [-1,1]. }$$
$$ \text {For any value of x beyond this bound, } x^2 \text {will be more than 1.} $$
$$ \text {Also, x cannot be negative. For x} \lt 0, \text {sin(x) is negative whereas } x^2 \text { is positive.}$$
$$ \text {So, x is within [0,1].}$$

In fact there will be only one value of x beyond x = 0, where they will be equal.

You can use multiple methods like Taylor's Series etc. to get an approximate value.

$$ \text {If you try with } \frac {\pi} {6} \text {, } \frac {\pi} {4} \text { and } \frac {\pi} {3}, \text { you realize the x is somewhere between }\frac {\pi} {4} \text { and } \frac {\pi} {3}.$$

Comment: By the way, to prove there is only one value beyond x = 0, you can do 2nd derivative of Sin(x) which is -Sin(x) which is negative whereas 2nd derivative of x^2 is positive, That tells you sin(x) is concave down and x^2 is concave up.

Answer (score 0):

The parabola $y=x^2$ is concave up and the sine curve $y=\sin x$ is concave down on the interval $[0,1]$, so the second root (which must lie in $[0,1]$) is unique. We can get a reasonable approximation by truncating $\sin x=x-{1\over6}x^3+{1\over120}x^5-\cdots$ at the cubic term, giving $x^2\approx x-{1\over6}x^3$, for which the resulting quadratic, $x^2+6x-1\approx0$, tells us $x\approx-3+\sqrt{9+6}=\sqrt{15}-3\approx0.873$. The actual solution is closer to $0.877$.